# Executing Perl script from Tcl

Tags: perl, tcl

I'm trying to execute a Perl script from Tcl.

I use `eval` in Tcl, and it executes the Perl script but doesn't execute the other command in my Tcl file.

Tcl:

```
eval perl perl_script
puts "Command executed"
```

Result: the Perl script is executed, but not the `puts` command. Why is this?

Comment: I don't know anything about `tcl`, but [this page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1017) says `eval` executes tcl passed to it as an argument rather than launch an external program (much like Perl's `eval EXPR` executes the Perl code in which `EXPR` results). I find your claim that this executes the Perl script doubtful, and I think that your problem will be solved if you actually used the correct function to launch a program.

Comment: In Tcl it's more suitble to use exec to run an external program, but even with exec i got the same behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In tcl, `eval` executes its arguments as tcl code, similar to its perl equivalent. But, you do not want this, instead you need to launch the perl interpreter as an external process and ask this interpreter to execute the script passed in its commandline. This is the job of `exec` in tcl.

```
exec perl perl_script
```

Read more about exec @ https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm

**UPDATE**

`exec` will throw an error when the command returns a non-zero exit status. You need wrap `exec` with a `catch` to continue with non zero exit status. See [WORKING WITH NON-ZERO RESULTS](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm#M29)

**UPDATE 2**

The reason why `eval perl script_path` manages to successfully launch the perl interpreter is tcl's `unknown` magic. It is likely that you do not have tcl proc named perl. So, tcl calls the "unknown" proc, which tries to handle this exception intelligently by calling `exec` on its arguments since it finds an executable in `$env(PATH)`. You can try `info body unknown` to see how this magic actually works.

Comment: The `unknown` magic is long, magical, and likely to scare the horses. Don't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
exec sh -c { perl -ape 's/this/that/' tmp.1 > tmp.11 }
```

It works for me.